# python - Getting tweepy authentication from password and username

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I'm using tweepy's streaming service and want to be able to have multiple users (on different computers) access this. This rules out the use of a single set of oauth identifications. How can I get this authentication using just the username and password of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter no longer supports Basic Auth (using usernames and passwords). However, Twitter does provide [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth), which allows you to use a username and password, but only if you *really* need to.

Couldn't you store different OAuth tokens, one for each user?